# Receiving this error in Java. error: not a statement when trying to use the (+) addition operator

Tags: java

I have spent about an hour perusing through google and SO trying to find a duplicate for my problem with no luck.  Here is my snippet of code

```
      public String toString()
            {
              String note = "Vehicle: " + this.getVehicles() +
              "The max speed in mph is: " + this.getSpeed() +
              " The number of cylinders is: " + this.getCylinders(); +
              " The cost per cylinder, per hour, is: " + cost_per_cylinder_per_hour;                 
              return note;
            }
```

I get the "not a statement" error on the very last + symbol, and I can't seem to figure out why the previous uses of + are fine, but that last one causes the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the semicolon `;` before `+`, like this

```
public String toString() {
      String note = "Vehicle: " + this.getVehicles() +
      "The max speed in mph is: " + this.getSpeed() +
      " The number of cylinders is: " + this.getCylinders() +
      " The cost per cylinder, per hour, is: " + cost_per_cylinder_per_hour;                 
      return note;
    }
```

Comment: My eyes must be getting tired to have missed that. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes I will. Just have to wait for the timer.